# Is every real Lie algebra with an Abelian ideal necessarily a semidirect sum?

Tags: symmetry, lie-algebras

Reposted from physics.SE. Hope the formulation of the question will be clear as it is. Do let me know in case I should be more clear or precise!

Suppose that we have a physical system with some symmetry, given by a Lie group whose generators are $Q_i$. Suppose that there is a (linearly independent) subset of these generators, $Q_A$, which commute with one another, and in general satisfy the relation
$$
[Q_i,Q_A]=(T_i)^B_{\phantom BA}Q_B,
$$
where the matrices $T_i$ define a representation of the Lie algebra of $Q_i$. Is it always possible to find a basis of the Lie algebra of the form $\{Q_a,Q_A\}$, where the generators $Q_a$ themselves form a closed subalgebra?

An example of such a structure would be the group $\text{ISO}(n)$ of isometries of the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space. Out of its generators, the $n$ translations form an Abelian ideal (my $Q_A$), whereas the $n(n-1)/2$ rotations form a non-Abelian subalgebra (my $Q_a$). The whole group $\text{ISO}(n)$ is a semidirect product of the subgroups of rotations and translations.

I believe that the answer to my question is in general *no*, but I would love to see some (possibly simple) examples.

Comment: I imagine the jargon you use here would be familiar to the users on math.se, and they would certainly be better qualified to answer this question. The question 'is every finite group with an Abelian normal subgroup necessarily a semidirect product' is answered in the negative: $\mathbb{Z}_4 \neq \mathbb{Z}_2 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$. I don't know enough to generalise this idea to the case of Lie groups, but if one could do so I suspect a counterexample to your statement about Lie algebras could be straightforwardly constructed.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: This wikipedia page might be interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_extension

Comment: @gj255 Thanks for the comment and the link! I am aware of the discrete counterexample, which is why my expectation is that also for Lie groups, the answer to my question is negative. I have already seen the Wikipedia page you mention, I may have missed something relevant though, so I will check it out once more.

Comment: @Qmechanic I will give it a try. The point of posting the question here was that I am a physicist, and so I was hoping to get an answer here in a language that I am more familiar with :)

Comment: The answer to your title question taken literally is "yes": Every Lie algebra is a semidirect sum of itself with $0$. But I assume you mean "a semidirect sum *of that ideal with some subalgebra*". Sorry for being pedantic.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Haha, you got me there! :) You are right, that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no.

(Background for those reading who aren't familiar with physicists' conventions: it's a common thing in physics to ignore the difference between Lie algebras and Lie groups, and also to ignore the difference between Lie groups with the same Lie algebra; in particular "generators" here means generators of a Lie algebra.)

I interpret the question to mean the following. Suppose $\mathfrak{g}$ is a (real) Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{a}$ an abelian ideal of it. Is $\mathfrak{g}$ the semidirect product of $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{a}$, with the adjoint action? Equivalently, does the short exact sequence

$$0 \to \mathfrak{a} \to \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{a} \to 0$$

split (as a short exact sequence of Lie algebras)?

Consider the special case where the action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $\mathfrak{a}$ is as simple as possible: the trivial representation. (So all the $T_i$ are zero.) In this case you're asking whether $\mathfrak{g}$ is a direct product of $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{a}$, and the answer is no: $\mathfrak{g}$ can be what is called a [central extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Central_extension) instead. Such extensions are classified by second [Lie algebra cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_cohomology)

$$H^2(\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{a})$$

(actually this true even if $\mathfrak{a}$ isn't central, but then it has to be understood as cohomology with nontrivial coefficients). You don't hear about these often in connection with the Lie algebras that show up in physics because $H^2(\mathfrak{g}, -)$ vanishes if $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple (this is Whitehead's second lemma), which leads to the [Levi decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi_decomposition) expressing any finite-dimensional real Lie algebra as the semidirect product of a solvable ideal and a semisimple quotient. The decomposition of $\mathfrak{iso}(n)$ you describe is an example of this.

The simplest example of a nontrivial central extension occurs when $\mathfrak{a} \cong \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{a} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$; it's given by the [Heisenberg Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) of $3 \times 3$ strictly upper triangular matrices

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & x & y \\ 0 & 0 & z \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right].$$

More generally, a Lie algebra is [nilpotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_Lie_algebra) iff it can be expressed as an iterated central extension of abelian Lie algebras. Examples include the Lie algebra of $n \times n$ strictly upper triangular matrices for all $n$.

An important class of examples of central extensions, which show up in "physics" for some value of physics, is the [affine Lie algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_Lie_algebra).

Comment: Haha. It's funny how a question can trigger answers as similar as ours at the same time. Yours gives more background though, +1.

Comment: I take the criticism of my sloppy language :) I should have thought of central extensions, but you made the point: it's not the first thing that comes to a physicist's mind since we mostly deal with semisimple Lie algebras. Thanks for the very useful answer with lots of material to think about!

Answer (score 3):

Every (finite-dimensional) Lie algebra $L$ over $\mathbb{R}$ (or any field with characteristic 0) is a semidirect product of its radical $R(L)$ with a copy of $L/R(L)$. That is the [theorem of Levi-Mal'tsev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi_decomposition). So if your abelian ideal happens to be the radical of the Lie algebra (which is as big as it can get), yes.

In general, no. Counterexample: $L = \{\pmatrix{0&a&c\\0&0&b\\0&0&0}: a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and as abelian ideal we take its centre $Z(L) = \{\pmatrix{0&0&c\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}: c \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Note that $L/Z(L)$ is abelian, and since $Z(L)$ is central, a semidirect product of $L/Z(L)$ and $Z(L)$ would actually be a direct product, hence abelian. But $L$ is not abelian.

Comment: Thanks for the nice example and for reminding me of the Levi decomposition! I vaguely recall this from my university classes, but the memory is too passive so that the pieces didn't fall into place before I asked the question.